# Current datetime shouldnt pass the validation using @Past annotation

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I need the @Past to error when the field is set to `now`. I realize that the `now` value on the field, and the `now` value used when the validator is comparing would be slightly different, thus the need to set the tolerance in hibernate validator.

Problem is that i can not get this to work. Here is the junit:

```
@Test
public void testHibernateValidator_withPast_withTodayDate() {
    // populates with 'now'
    MyFormWithPast form = new MyFormWithPast();
    form.setDt(OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
            .configure()
            .clockProvider(() -> Clock.systemUTC())
            // adds tolerance so that when comparing, the form dt and 'now' is considered equal, 
            //   therefore dt is not a past datetime
            .temporalValidationTolerance(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .buildValidatorFactory();

    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyFormWithPast>> errors = validator.validate(form);

    // needs to fail, since 'now' shouldn't be considered 'past'
    assertFalse("now shoudnt be considered as Past", errors.isEmpty());
}

public static class MyFormWithPast {
    @Past
    private OffsetDateTime dt;

    public void setDt(OffsetDateTime dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
}
```

I expect the validation to fail when i put in 'now' in the field, as 'now' shouldnt be considered as 'past'. What did i miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporal validation tolerance was designed to be more lenient, not stricter. You want it to be stricter.

I think you will need your own constraints to deal with what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my current solution, adding a default of 1 minute forward tolerance so that inputted 'now' is not considered a 'past'.

The annotation:

```
/**
 * Validates that the date is of the past, with forward tolerance of 1 minute, 
 *   to offset the time to create a 'now' instance to compare to.
 * The usage is when user selects 'today' in the UI, we dont want it to be considered as 'Past'
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341963/current-datetime-shouldnt-pass-the-validation-using-past-annotation
 * Annotation is applicable to {@link OffsetDateTime}.
 */
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy=StrictPastValidator.class)
public @interface StrictPast {

    public static final String MESSAGE = "{constraints.StrictPast.message}";

    /**
     * @return The error message template.
     */
    String message() default MESSAGE;

    /**
     * @return The groups the constraint belongs to.
     */
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    /**
     * @return The payload associated to the constraint
     */
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

The validator:

```
public class StrictPastValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StrictPast, Object> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(StrictPast annotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object input, ConstraintValidatorContext ignored) {
        if (input == null) {
             return true;
        } else if (input instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
            return isValidOffsetDateTime((OffsetDateTime) input);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("StrictPastValidator is not applicable to the field type " + input.getClass().getName());
    }

    private boolean isValidOffsetDateTime(OffsetDateTime input) {
        OffsetDateTime plusSecondsDt = input.plusSeconds(Duration.ofMinutes(1).getSeconds());
        return plusSecondsDt.isBefore(OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
    }

}
```